# How do I check if the download completed in onCreate android fetch library?

Tags: android, file, download, fetch, android-library

How do I check if the download completed in onCreate fetch library?
The following code work without problem, but maybe user cancel the download operation before completion and incomplete file exists in the path.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FetchObserver<Download> {

    private Button Edame, tavaghof, DownloadImage, online;
    public static TextView etaTextView;
    public static TextView downloadSpeedTextView;
    public static Request request;
    public static Fetch fetch;
    public static ProgressBar progressBar;
    public static TextView progressTextView;
    private LinearLayout dllaye;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File path = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/telavat/" + "naba.mp3");
            if (path.exists()) {
                dllaye.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        FetchConfiguration fetchConfiguration = new FetchConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(3)
                .build();

        fetch = Fetch.Impl.getInstance(fetchConfiguration);

        DownloadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    enqueueDownload();
            }
        });

        Edame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fetch.resume(request.getId());
            }
        });
        tavaghof.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fetch.pause(request.getId());
            }
        });

//EndOnceate
    }


    private void enqueueDownload() {
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        final String url = "https://amoozesh3.ir/play/naba.mp3";
        final String filePath = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/telavatquran/" + Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        request = new Request(url, filePath);
        request.setExtras(getExtrasForRequest(request));

        fetch.attachFetchObserversForDownload(request.getId(), this)
                .enqueue(request, new Func<Request>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(@NotNull Request result) {
                        request = result;
                    }
                }, new Func<Error>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(@NotNull Error result) {
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (request != null) {
            fetch.attachFetchObserversForDownload(request.getId(), this);
        }
    }

   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (request != null) {
            fetch.removeFetchObserversForDownload(request.getId(), this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       fetch.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(Download data, @NotNull Reason reason) {
        updateViews(data, reason);
    }

    private Extras getExtrasForRequest(Request request) {
        final MutableExtras extras = new MutableExtras();
        extras.putBoolean("testBoolean", true);
        extras.putString("testString", "test");
        extras.putFloat("testFloat", Float.MIN_VALUE);
        extras.putDouble("testDouble", Double.MIN_VALUE);
        extras.putInt("testInt", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        extras.putLong("testLong", Long.MAX_VALUE);
        return extras;
    }

    private void updateViews(@NotNull Download download, Reason reason) {
        if (request.getId() == download.getId()) {
            if (reason == Reason.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED) {
                dllaye.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File download successful",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            setProgressView(download.getStatus(), download.getProgress());

            etaTextView.setText(Utils.getETAString(this, download.getEtaInMilliSeconds()));
            downloadSpeedTextView.setText(Utils.getDownloadSpeedString(this, download.getDownloadedBytesPerSecond()));

        }
    }


    private void setProgressView(@NonNull final Status status, final int progress) {

        switch (status) {
            case QUEUED: {
                progressTextView.setText(R.string.queued);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                break;
            }
            case ADDED: {
                progressTextView.setText(R.string.added);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                break;
            }
            case DOWNLOADING: {
                if (progress == -1) {
                    progressTextView.setText(R.string.downloading);
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                } else {
                    final String progressString = getResources().getString(R.string.percent_progress, progress);
                    progressTextView.setText(progressString);
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
                break;
            }

            case COMPLETED: {

                break;
            }
            default: {
                progressTextView.setText(R.string.status_unknown);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to free up more space on the screen after downloading

How can I understand the download is completed?

I’d appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: To clarify, you are attempting to determine if a previously downloaded mp3 file has any missing "frames"/[audio data]?

Comment: There is no download in your code. And no onCreate(). And you did not tell when the download was started. And how.

Comment: @blackapps: Method download in my code added.

Comment: @Elletlar : Yes

Comment: `How do I check if the download completed in onCreate`. That is impossible ad onCreate has long finished before even the user had a chance to start/enque the download.

Comment: Yes you are right it cannot be handled in onCreate. You need to create an 'asynchronous' solution. In your code so far, onCreate is setting the content view, adding click handle to initiate a download and running to completion on the main thread. Meanwhile, in a separate thread the actual download is happening. Once the download is complete, "public void call(@NotNull Request result)" will be called. From there, you can add additional code that updates your UI.

Comment: Another important point, from your question it seems that you believe enqueueDownload is being run inside onCreate. It is not. After the onCreate method ceases to exist, the user will click on the button and a new method will be created on the main thread onClick. Keep in mind, onCreate is only initialising a callback that will be called after onCreate ceases to exist.

Comment: @Elletlar: Thank you very much for your comment. 
How can I updates my UI in "public void call(@NotNull Request result)" ? 
I added code: dllaye.setVisibility(View.GONE); in "public void call(@NotNull Request result)" but it doesn't update

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on it in the debugger to see if it is being called? It should either call that method or else "public void call(@NotNull Error result) " if the download request was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Elletlar: No I can't do that. It's complicated for me.

Comment: You could add a log statement like: Log.i("Test", "Success") and another like Log.i("Test", "Failed") and then search on the "Logcat" tab to see which one was called.

Comment: Or adding a like, like: "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success",
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();" might be easier...

Comment: @Elletlar: I added like the following code result = "Success"
fetch.attachFetchObserversForDownload(request.getId(), this)
        .enqueue(request, new Func<Request>() {
           Override
            public void call(NotNull Request result) {
                request = result;
                Log.i("Test", "Success");
                            }
        }, new Func<Error>() {
            Override
            public void call(NotNull Error result) {
                Log.i("Test", "Failed");
            }
        });

Comment: It showed the success toast message?

Comment: @Elletlar: Yes that showed the success toast message.

Comment: That's good. You should be able to update your views now or do whatever you need with the downloaded data.